# AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests test case updates cassandra database

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-jpa, testng, integration-testing

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = RepositoryMain.class)
@ActiveProfiles({"dev"})
public class EmployeeTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Test
    public void testAddEmployee() {
        /// some logic
    }
}
```

This `testAddEmployee()` test case inserts a record into the Cassandra database employee table. When I write the same test for MySQL repository, it keeps the MySQL state intact before and after the test case.

Why does `AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests` not work with Cassandra? Is it because Cassandra does not support commit and rollup functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests not work with Cassandra? Is it because Cassandra does not support commit and rollup functionality?

Yes, this correct.

The database cleanup that you see with MySQL is achieved by a rollback, but this doesn't work for Cassandra.

You'll have to do the cleanup explicitly.